# function "if " applied to each cell

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I am trying perform a function to each cell of a matrix in R. I want to add the cells per 3 if they are > 0.

Example:

```
mat <- matrix(data=0:9, nrow=5, ncol=10, byrow=F)
mat3 <- apply(mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN= function(mat) if(mat != 0) {mat+3})
```

But first that created a list of length 5 and second it's all the cells who are added per 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple case, it would be preferable to use the solutions from @akrun or @Karolis Koncevičius, but you can also do:

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 0, x + 3, x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    8    0    8    0    8    0    8    0     8
[2,]    4    9    4    9    4    9    4    9    4     9
[3,]    5   10    5   10    5   10    5   10    5    10
[4,]    6   11    6   11    6   11    6   11    6    11
[5,]    7   12    7   12    7   12    7   12    7    12
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any apply, can use `ifelse` directly:

```
ifelse(mat > 0, mat+3, mat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    8    0    8    0    8    0    8    0     8
[2,]    4    9    4    9    4    9    4    9    4     9
[3,]    5   10    5   10    5   10    5   10    5    10
[4,]    6   11    6   11    6   11    6   11    6    11
[5,]    7   12    7   12    7   12    7   12    7    12
```

But a faster solution would be:

```
mat[mat > 0] <- mat[mat > 0] + 3
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    8    0    8    0    8    0    8    0     8
[2,]    4    9    4    9    4    9    4    9    4     9
[3,]    5   10    5   10    5   10    5   10    5    10
[4,]    6   11    6   11    6   11    6   11    6    11
[5,]    7   12    7   12    7   12    7   12    7    12
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also do this on the fly with

```
mat + (mat > 0) * 3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    0    8    0    8    0    8    0    8    0     8
#[2,]    4    9    4    9    4    9    4    9    4     9
#[3,]    5   10    5   10    5   10    5   10    5    10
#[4,]    6   11    6   11    6   11    6   11    6    11
#[5,]    7   12    7   12    7   12    7   12    7    12
```